# Maven build success with several warnings while downloading dependency from remote repository BitBucket

Tags: java, git, maven, bitbucket, maven-metadata

I would like to can download a dependency present on BitBucket remote repository from an another project Maven. To reply the case I've created a remote repository like this: https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo

Then, I've created two projects Maven: **test** and **test2** (The project **test** has only a static method of testing).

Here's **test** project's POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>internal repository</id>
            <url>https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Maven Central</id>
            <url>http://repo.apache.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

while here's **test2** project's POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>internal repository</id>
            <url>https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Maven Central</id>
            <url>http://repo.apache.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I've taken the following steps:

1. Installed the project **test** on the local repository Maven with
   command: `mvn clean install -DcreateChecksum=true`
2. Copied the project **test** (as such as org/test/test) from local repository Maven to the folder /git-repo/mvn-repo, then I've pushed on BitBucket remote repository.
3. Removed folders org/test/test from local repository Maven.
4. Executed command: `mvn clean install -DcreateChecksum=true` under the project folder **test2**.

This is the result

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< org.test:test2 >---------------------------
[INFO] Building test2 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from internal repository: https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Progress (1): 1.1 kB
Progress (1): 1.5 kB

[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is 76a18682367c7eaeca8fb5d2bb5006d22d76280b from internal repository for https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Progress (1): 1.1 kB
Progress (1): 1.5 kB
[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is 3b29c9ec739d87fb529567cc27e22b3d7d5c4feb

[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is 3b29c9ec739d87fb529567cc27e22b3d7d5c4feb from internal repository for https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from internal repository: https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.5 kB at 248 B/s)
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-internal repository.xml is invalid: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...t>\nvar elements = document.forms[0].elements;\nfor (var i = 0; i < ... @10:21) 
[WARNING] The metadata C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-internal repository.xml is invalid: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...t>\nvar elements = document.forms[0].elements;\nfor (var i = 0; i < ... @10:21) 
Downloading from internal repository: https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Progress (1): 1.1 kB
Progress (1): 1.5 kB

[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is bcb4b6aa3538fce8d8a804e9727bb7866e65681d from internal repository for https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Progress (1): 1.1 kB
Progress (1): 1.5 kB
[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom: Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is 3546a61a9b568724edfc34f29b202cbafa0e8769

[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is 3546a61a9b568724edfc34f29b202cbafa0e8769 from internal repository for https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloaded from internal repository: https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom (1.5 kB at 282 B/s)
[WARNING] The POM for org.test:test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
Downloading from internal repository: https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Progress (1): 1.1 kB
Progress (1): 1.5 kB

[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is c30cfc686fdc8a1aedb311222b4af1b3b5780e9e from internal repository for https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Progress (1): 1.1 kB
Progress (1): 1.5 kB
[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is c0a924f008f5bc6fe27dfc0344e9f18f34e09efb

[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is c0a924f008f5bc6fe27dfc0344e9f18f34e09efb from internal repository for https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Downloaded from internal repository: https://bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar (1.5 kB at 300 B/s)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ test2 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\[user]\eclipse-workspace-oxygen\test2\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ test2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ test2 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\[user]\eclipse-workspace-oxygen\test2\target\classes
[WARNING] error reading C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar; error in opening zip file
[WARNING] error reading C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar; error in opening zip file
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ test2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ test2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ test2 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ test2 ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\[user]\eclipse-workspace-oxygen\test2\target\test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ test2 ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\[user]\eclipse-workspace-oxygen\test2\target\test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test2\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\[user]\eclipse-workspace-oxygen\test2\pom.xml to C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test2\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\test2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.060 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-14T20:38:42+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Maven build shows several warnings even if it returns a build success. The file test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar result be corrupted. How can I resolve the problem? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

**UPDATE**

I've changed the test project's POM for attempting to execute the command `mvn deploy -X`, however Maven returns the same result:

```
Downloading from internal repository: https://my_user@bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is d409bb497c4f4faa046afbad1028304f2fc3fcf2 from internal repository for https://my_user@bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not validate integrity of download from https://my_user@bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException: Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is fe062c89ef7cbebdf7ed304fd17eab147d9b7c5a
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validateExternalChecksums (ChecksumValidator.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ChecksumValidator.validate (ChecksumValidator.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)

[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <html> but is fe062c89ef7cbebdf7ed304fd17eab147d9b7c5a from internal repository for https://my_user@bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from internal repository: https://my_user@bitbucket.org/[user]/mvn-repo/raw/master/org/test/test/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.5 kB at 248 B/s)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.473 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-09-22T20:37:00+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test: Failed to update metadata org.test:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-internal repository.xml: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...t>\nvar elements = document.forms[0].elements;\nfor (var i = 0; i < ... @10:21)  -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project test: Failed to update metadata org.test:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-internal repository.xml: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...t>\nvar elements = document.forms[0].elements;\nfor (var i = 0; i < ... @10:21)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to update metadata org.test:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-internal repository.xml: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...t>\nvar elements = document.forms[0].elements;\nfor (var i = 0; i < ... @10:21)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to update metadata org.test:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-internal repository.xml: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...t>\nvar elements = document.forms[0].elements;\nfor (var i = 0; i < ... @10:21)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to update metadata org.test:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-internal repository.xml: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...t>\nvar elements = document.forms[0].elements;\nfor (var i = 0; i < ... @10:21)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload (DefaultDeployer.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute (DeployMojo.java:157)

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.RepositoryException: Could not parse metadata C:\Users\[user]\.m2\repository\org\test\test\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-internal repository.xml: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...t>\nvar elements = document.forms[0].elements;\nfor (var i = 0; i < ... @10:21)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.MavenMetadata.read (MavenMetadata.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.MavenMetadata.merge (MavenMetadata.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload (DefaultDeployer.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy (DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy (AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)

Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: unexpected character in markup   (position: START_TAG seen ...t>\nvar elements = document.forms[0].elements;\nfor (var i = 0; i < ... @10:21)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl (MXParser.java:1523)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next (MXParser.java:1317)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.checkUnknownElement (MetadataXpp3Reader.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.parseMetadata (MetadataXpp3Reader.java:676)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read (MetadataXpp3Reader.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read (MetadataXpp3Reader.java:557)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.MavenMetadata.read (MavenMetadata.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.MavenMetadata.merge (MavenMetadata.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.upload (DefaultDeployer.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy (DefaultDeployer.java:268)

[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: You need to pass up this "user" on url via maven property. When maven try to download it creates a corrupted version in your .m2 repository. Try deleting this parent dependency from .m2 folder and build again.

Answer (score 1):

try this on your pom:

```
<properties>
    <bitBucketUser>${user}</bitBucketUser>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>internal repository</id>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/${bitBucketUser}/mvn-repo/raw/master/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>Maven Central</id>
        <url>http://repo.apache.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and then execute your clean install `mvn clean install -Duser=yourBitBucketUser`

Comment: I don't figure out what you want to say. Perhaps there was a misunderstanding. Actually, what you see like **[user]** is BitBucket's my user.

Comment: I know. I mean, don't you need to pass this user as parameter/property? Or you just hid it? Sorry if I misunderstand you. In case you hid it, looks like your dependency is corrupted. Try to delete from your .m2 repository and download again.

Comment: What i do is to delete the project **test** every time from my .m2 repository. Then I go to the project **test2** and execute the commands `mvn clean install` (Here it should download my dependency **test** from BitBucket remote repository and install test and test2 into the local folder .m2, but It keep giving errors).

When you say "looks like your dependency is corrupted" you're right. In fact, happens when i only download my dependency from remote repository.

Comment: Maybe your dependency in your bitbucket remote repo might be corrupted.

Comment: I've checked my test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar on remote repo and It doesn't result corrupted. What's your solution to you?